# Специфическая маска для полей input. Возможно ли?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте! У меня в форме есть два поля input. В одном поле мне нужно сделать так, чтобы можно было вводить числа только кратные 7-и, т.е. 7, 14, 21, 28 и т.д. В другом поле только тысячные - 1 000, 2 000, 3 000 ... 10 000, 20 000 ... 400 000, 500 000 и т.д., т.е. другими словами - 1 шаг = числу 1 000. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно это сделать? Спасибо!

```html
<input type="text" name="stat" id="stat" class="f_input" />
<input type="text" name="din" id="din" class="f_input" />
```

Comment: ну числа же - не цифры

Comment: Именно маску - невозможно. Валидацию - возможно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("#stat").on("keyup", function(){
  var v = +$(this).val();
  $("#stat_result").text(v * 7);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="stat" id="stat" class="f_input" /> x 7 = <span  id="stat_result"></span>
```

Comment: Вы читали условие? Нужен не калькулятор а фильтр для ввода

Comment: @user202854 Мы читали условие. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно есть смысл глянуть в эту сторону, атрибут pattern 
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp
Пример для тысяч:

```
<form action="">
  <input title="Error message" type="text" pattern="\d*?0{3}">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Или же писать свой js код на событие например потери фокуса инпута и проверять верно ли пользователь ввел данные

Пример можно найти здесь https://learn.javascript.ru/focus-blur
Дальше сменить условие проверки на число на нужное для вас.

```
<style> .error { border-color: red; } </style>

Введите ваш возраст: <input type="text" id="input">

<div id="error"></div>

<script>
input.onblur = function() {
  if (isNaN(this.value)) { // введено не число
    // показать ошибку
    this.className = "error";
    error.innerHTML = 'Вы ввели не число. Исправьте, пожалуйста.';
  }elseif(this.value%7){
    this.className = "error";
    error.innerHTML = 'Вы ввели число не кратное 7. Исправьте, пожалуйста.';
  }
};

input.onfocus = function() {
  if (this.className == 'error') { // сбросить состояние "ошибка", если оно есть
    this.className = "";
    error.innerHTML = "";
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Ну почти все написали, доделайте проверку числа на кратность в else { }

Comment: добавил условие кратности 7, условие кратности 1000 так  же можно проверять